# Is there any way to increase your carrying weight with max strength and power armor?

Tags: fallout-4

Is it possible to increse my carry weight with having max strength and t60b power armor? I was over my carry weight in the glowing sea and didnt have a place to fast travel back to.

Comment: I think there is a perk in Charisma that gives you extra carrying capacity if you don't have a companion

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a few ways that you can increase your max carry capacity, some temporary and some permanent.

**Permanent perk solutions** (these are only feasible in your current situation if you have a spare perk point and the required SPECIAL stats)

1. Strong Back (6 STR required): You can get +25/+50 carry capacity for the first 2 ranks of this perk, if you don't have it yet. Also, if you are not on the new Survival difficulty, the 4th point in this perk allows you to fast travel while over-encumbered.
2. Lone Wanderer (3 CHR required): If you are traveling with a companion and have this perk, dismiss them for an instant +50/+100 carry weight increase, depending how many points you have in the perk. For extra weight relief, trade with them and fill up their inventory with items from your inventory before sending them off.

**Temporary Solutions**

Any consumable that gives you temporary Strength will also temporarily increase your carry weight. Each point of strength from the consumable will give you 10 carry capacity, per the [Fallout Wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Carry_Weight). Moreover, some of these can stack, [according to this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/245233/122225). Consumables that increase strength include:

1. Beer (STR+1)
2. Bobrov's Best Moonshine (STR+1)
3. Bourbon (STR+1)
4. Dirty Wastelander (STR+3)
5. All Gwinnett Beers/Iced Gwinnett Beers (STR+1)
6. Poisoned Wine, Wine (STR+1)
7. Rum (STR+1)
8. Whiskey (STR+2)
9. Buffout (STR+2)
10. Buffjet/Bufftats/Psychobuff (STR+3)
11. Mysterious Serum (STR+5)
12. X-Cell (STR+2)

[Grilled Radstag](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Grilled_radstag) also gives a direct +25 to carry capacity. However, unless you grilled some beforehand or have radstag meat and a cooking station nearby, that won't help you out.

Outside of consumables, there are also a couple of tricks that can help you carry more when in an over-encumbered situation.

1. You can drop your heaviest item and 'carry' it. After dropping the heaviest item from your inventory, you can hold down the 'interact' button while looking at it to pick it up and hold it out in front of you. It will not count against your carry weight. And, if by doing this you go below the max weight threshold, it will allow you to run somewhere where you can store your items.
2. If with a companion, there is a sort of exploit that allows them to carry unlimited weight. Per the [Fallout Wiki page on companions](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_companions):

> All companions can carry an unlimited quantity of loot: rather than trade with them, place the items you want them to carry on a dead body or in a storage container then command them to to grab anything worthwhile. You can also make them pick up items laying on the ground one item at a time.

**Other long-term solutions**

After you get out of your current predicament... There are some other things you can do to ensure this doesn't happen again. Outfitting your equipment with Pocketed or Deep Pocket (+5/+10 on arm/leg pieces, +10/+20 on chest) can also help with your carry weight. However, as you've stated you are using power armor (and your standard armor mods are not active while you are in power armor), modifying your power armor leg pieces with the mod [Calibrated Shocks](http://fallout.gamepedia.com/Calibrated_shocks) will give +50 carry capacity per leg, so +100 with the mod on both legs.

You can also determine your companion, should you travel with one, to be more focused towards carry capacity. Per the [Fallout Wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_companions), Strong and Danse have the highest carry capacities of the companions, at 200 and 210 respectively. Other companions have a limit of 150.

- Outfitting companions with 'Pocketed' or 'Deep Pocketed' modded equipment will also increase their carry weight.
- [Live & Love](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Live_%26_Love) issue #3 increases companion carry capacity by 10.
- Dogmeat does **not** count as a companion when determining bonuses from the `Lone Wanderer` Perk. You can, therefore, raise your carry capacity by 100 (and get all other bonuses of this perk) while traveling with Dogmeat (who has a carry capacity of 150, for an overall net gain of 250 weight between the two of you).

If you have the [fallout-4-automatron](/questions/tagged/fallout-4-automatron) DLC, robot companions can also be a great source of extra carry capacity. Most notably, robot companions with the Sentry Bot arms & legs offer the greatest carry weight boost. The equivalent Protectron pieces offer a decent increase in their carry capacity, and requires lower perk thresholds to use on your robot companion (per [a few](http://www.siliconera.com/2016/03/28/fallout-4s-automatron-robots-help-settlement-establishments/) [sources](http://fandom.wikia.com/articles/guide-fallout-4-automatron-dlc)).

**Console Solutions**

If you are playing on PC, you have access to the console. If you don't mind using it in your playthrough, carry weight can be modified using the following command (replace xx with the number you want your carry capacity to be increased by):

```
player.modav carryweight xx
```

You can also use `player.setav`. However, `modav` will modify your current carry weight capacity by the value you enter. This allows you to 'reset' your carry weight later, should you want to, by using the negative of the value you chose.

Comment: Nice job covering these, maybe it would be appropriate to mention the carry capacity of followers?

Comment: Also, the trick where you drop your heaviest item and than carry it "by hand" with you.

Comment: I have a question! If you consume more than one grilled radstag will it add more carry capacity?

Comment: @RichRek-ageKivlen No, unfortunately not. Using multiple of the same consumable does not stack, it just restarts the timer on the duration of it, as described in [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/243703/do-item-effects-stack-in-fallout-4/243713#243713). So, you can only get at max the +25 from the grilled radstag. If you stack that with some whiskey, buffout, or other +STR consumables mentioned in the answer, then you get stacked carry weight increase.

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer Thanks for the feedback, added those things in there, as well as a couple other tricks to prevent being over-encumbered.

Comment: If you have the Automatron DLC, you can modify your robots to increase their carrying capacity as well.

Comment: @DCShannon Ah, yeah that's right. I've added a section on that as well. There's so many ways that can be used to figuratively trim some weight, I keep coming back to this answer to edit it. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

Take all ranks of strong back,the sprinter perk that reduces sprint cost by half and both leg armor upgrades. Use legendary gear that increases ap regeneration.

You will never need to drop a thing.

I am running around the wasteland carrying over 200000 pounds of stuff.

Comment: "both leg upgrades"?

Comment: Upgrades that reduce sprint speed. Writing from phone so trying to be as short as possible

Comment: I like the idea. I'm curious how laggy your pip-boy inventory menu is, since I'm assuming you must have a boatload of items to add up to 200,000 lbs. My routine was to dump all of my spare gear into the sanctuary workbench, and had to clean it out recently because switching between item categories (and even vertical scrolling within that category) was getting very sluggish.

Comment: Also, you might want to point out that this might not be the ideal solution if playing on the new survival mode. Per the [Bethesda post](https://bethesda.net/#en/events/game/fallout-4s-all-new-survival-mode/2016/03/29/96): `Exceeding your carry weight reduces your overall Wellness, quickly building Fatigue, and will eventually cripple your legs. You can’t hoard a whole bunch of items, then make the long, slow trip back home – which, to be fair, isn’t that fun. Just set the loot aside and be free.`

Comment: I play on survival, no cripple or dmg if you have strong back 3 :) and yes, the inventory is extremely laggy when switching weapons